# Dynamic Content Fields

Tags: 7, entities

I am new to Drupal. using drupal 7

I would like to have dynamic fields in content type. 
basically i would like to allow users to add a content and in that content, fields should generate dynamically.

for example if user has select  CAR the next field (MODEL) should be generated dynamically according to first one having all the model for that particular car and so on.

i know about "hierarchical select" but its not good for me. conditional fields are still under development.

search a lot but did not come out with any solution. please help.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Despite your statement in your question, [Hierarchical Select](http://drupal.org/project/hierarchical_select) is the standard way to approach this sort of need.

There's likely no other stock solution for this, since no one bothered to duplicate HS.

Answer (score 0):

you can let the user create the content-type himself and let him add the fields with the fieldUI.

you'll probably need to put your focus of how to manage the content-types,
when should a new one be created, when can an existing be used ..

Comment: no, i only want them to select whats already  there. dont want them to create new fields. what i need is dynamic data in fields according to whats selected in the previous field. like if users selects BMW from the first field labled CRAS the next field should be updated with all the models of BMW.

Comment: have a look here http://drupal.org/node/1029420

Comment: or try directly [hierarchical select](http://drupal.org/project/hierarchical_select)